# How do I use vsts-task-lib to get the path where build task's files are dropped?

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

My custom build task is running on an agent, and its files are located at `E:\agent_work\_tasks\MyTaskName_106598a6-d5ba-4038-8dc8-ba0172210a94\0.0.13`. Is there a way to use vsts-task-lib to get this path?

If I were able to get the task id, name, and version sourced from the task.json, I could determine the path myself by doing something like, `tl.getVariable('Agent.WorkFolder') + '\\_tasks\\' + taskName + '_' + taskIdentifier + '\\' + taskVersion`.

I had my eyes on https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/vsts-task-lib.md#taskgetTaskVariable, but wasn't sure of the variable names to use or if this was even along the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current path by using `__dirname` (nodejs) or `$PSScriptRoot` (powershell) in your build/release task extension.

For example:

NodeJs:

`console.log(__dirname)`

PowerShell:

`Write-Host $PSScriptRoot`